# Show that there are infinitely many solutions $(t, d)$ to $c - d^2 = t^2$ where $2c-1 = 3t^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, sums-of-squares

Set $c = (3t^2+1)/2$.

Prove that infinitely many times, $c - t^2 = d^2$ for positive integers $t, d$. The first such instance is with $t = 1, d = 1$, and $t = 7, d = 5$. Can anyone come up with more solutions. Thanks for help.

$2 = (3\cdot1^2+1)/2$, and $2-1^2=1^2$

$74 = (3\cdot7^2+1)/2$, and $74-7^2=5^2$

Comment: Do you know about Pell's equations and continued fractions ?

Answer (score 2):

This is
$$\frac{3t^2+1}2-d^2=t^2$$
that is
$$t^2-2d^2=-1.$$
This is a [negative Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_negative_Pell_equation). Its positive solutions
are given by
$$t+d\sqrt2=(1+\sqrt2)^m$$
where $m$ is an **odd** positive integer.